# What is the return type of a Sproutcore query to a database, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sproutcore

```
    queryNote = SC.Query.local('Tree.Note',
            "categoryId = {categoryId}", {
            categoryId: this.get('guid'),
            orderBy: "name ASC"
        });
   var arrayCategory = Tree.store.find(queryTree);
```

What is the type of arrayCategory? I thought it would be an array of objects. But no Javascript array functions seem to work on it.

NOTE : I had initially asked what the type of queryNote was, by mistake. I actually want to know what arrayCategory was because I would like to append the results of one query to another.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.Query.html#method=.local), an instance of `SC.Query`, which is an object.

Comment: Hey sorry, I made an error. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrayCategory should be an SC.RecordArray: http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.RecordArray.html

Answer (score 2):

I googled SC.Query.local and found this:

http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.Query.html

About half way down the page it says this:

```
local
Returns a LOCAL query with the passed options.
```

and then below that:

```
Returns:
SC.Query
```

So I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest it returns an `SC.Query`

EDIT: After the edit to the OP, I took the step of googling 'sproutcore Tree.store.find' and I got this 'http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.Store.html#method=find'

Which says:

```
Returns:
SC.Record record instance or null
```

The docs should contain the answers you're looking for

Comment: Hey I'm sorry. I was about to edit the question when you replied. Could you check it again? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I should've checked the documentation properly before asking. :@ To be more precise, the return type is SC.RecordArray